# ¿Qué pasa si en una transacción en MySQL llamo un trigger y ocurre un error?

Tags: mysql, trigger, transacciones

Estoy trabajando en un sistema de gestión de ventas y me surgió una duda, al realizar una transacción en mysql y dentro de las instrucciones existe un llamado a un procedimiento almacenado y si por "x" motivos ocurriera un error, los cambios producidos por el trigger también volverían a su estado anterior si invoco a RollBack

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Los cambios del disparador (trigger) forman parte de la transacción, por ello, los cambios se revierten al hacer `ROLLBACK`.

Ejemplo:

```sql
mysql> SELECT VERSION();
+-----------+
| VERSION() |
+-----------+
| 5.7.19    |
+-----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `sp_transaction`; 
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `tbl_one`;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tbl_one` (
    ->   `id` BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    ->   `value` INT
    -> ) ENGINE=InnoDB;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> CREATE TRIGGER `ins_value` BEFORE INSERT ON `tbl_one`
    -> FOR EACH ROW
    -> SET NEW.`value` := NEW.`value` * 100;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> DELIMITER //

mysql> CREATE PROCEDURE `sp_transaction`(`error` BOOL)
    -> BEGIN
    ->   START TRANSACTION;
    ->   INSERT INTO `tbl_one` (`id`, `value`)
    ->   VALUES (1, `error`);
    ->   IF `error` THEN
    ->     ROLLBACK;
    ->   ELSE
    ->     COMMIT;
    ->   END IF;
    -> END//
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> DELIMITER ;

mysql> CALL `sp_transaction`(1); -- ROLLBACK
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT `id`, `value`
    -> FROM `tbl_one`;
Empty set (0.01 sec)

mysql> CALL `sp_transaction`(0); -- COMMIT
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT `id`, `value`
    -> FROM `tbl_one`;
+----+-------+
| id | value |
+----+-------+
|  1 |     0 |
+----+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Ver [db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ht2xf7xSWZwUnffWCN72g/1).

Answer (score 2):

El modelo teórico de las transacciones es [ACID (Atomicidad, Consistencia, Aislamiento (*Isolation*) y Durabilidad](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID):

> Atomicidad: Si cuando una operación consiste en una serie de pasos, bien todos ellos se ejecutan o bien ninguno, es decir, las transacciones son completas.
>
> Consistencia: (Integridad). Es la propiedad que asegura que sólo se empieza aquello que se puede acabar. Por lo tanto se ejecutan aquellas operaciones que no van a romper las reglas y directrices de Integridad de la base de datos. La propiedad de consistencia sostiene que cualquier transacción llevará a la base de datos desde un estado válido a otro también válido. "La Integridad de la Base de Datos nos permite asegurar que los datos son exactos y consistentes, es decir que estén siempre intactos, sean siempre los esperados y que de ninguna manera cambien ni se deformen. De esta manera podemos garantizar que la información que se presenta al usuario será siempre la misma."
>
> Aislamiento: Esta propiedad asegura que una operación no puede afectar a otras. Esto asegura que la realización de dos transacciones sobre la misma información sean independientes y no generen ningún tipo de error.  Esta propiedad define cómo y cuándo los cambios producidos por una operación se hacen visibles para las demás operaciones concurrentes. El aislamiento puede alcanzarse en distintos niveles, siendo el parámetro esencial a la hora de seleccionar SGBDs.
>
> Durabilidad: (Persistencia). Esta propiedad asegura que una vez realizada la operación, ésta persistirá y no se podrá deshacer aunque falle el sistema y que de esta forma los datos sobrevivan de alguna manera.

Lo importante es la *atomicidad*, o se ejecutan todos los cambios o ninguno.

Según este [artículo](http://ronaldbradford.com/blog/q-does-mysql-support-acid-a-yes-2016-06-29/)(aunque supongo que habrá muchos otros), desde hace tiempo InnoDB soporta ACID; el principal problema era que MySQL por defecto usaba MyISAM que no soporta ACID. Desde la 5.5, MySQL usa InnoDB por defecto.

**TL;DR:** Desde la versión 3.3 de MySQL InnoDB está disponible con soporte de atomicidad. A partir de la 5.5 es el motor por defecto. Si hay atomicidad, está garantizado que o se modifican todos los datos o no se modifica ninguno.